# When I pressed knit to HTML, it said, "Error: Parser can't have multibyte characters in line 24, stop execution,"

Tags: r, r-markdown

````
# my Rmarkdown files  

title: "shopping_p78t5"  
author: '197103027'  
date: "2021/11/12"  
output:  
  html_document:  
    fig_width: 15  
    fig_height: 8  
  word_document: default   
  pdf_document: default  
editor_options:   
  chunk_output_type: console  

# (a)

```{r echo=TRUE,include=TRUE,highlight=TRUE}
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r echo=TRUE,include=TRUE,highlight=TRUE}
shopdata<-read.csv("C:/Users/86176/Desktop/study/Data Mining/all data/data-exe/shopping.csv",colClasses = c(rep("numeric",10),rep("character",5)))
shopdata<-shopdata%>%mutate(across(where(is.integer),factor))%>%mutate(across(where(is.character),factor))%>%as_tibble()
```

# (b)

```{r echo=TRUE,include=TRUE,highlight=TRUE}
rules<-apriori(shopdata,parameter = list(supp=0.8,conf=0.8,target="rules"))
summary(rules)
rules_pruned<-rules[!is.redundant(rules)]
options(digits = 4)
inspect(rules_pruned)
plot(rules_pruned,method = "graph")
```

# (c)

```{r echo=TRUE,include=TRUE,highlight=TRUE,results='hold'}
rules_rhs_ready_made<-apriori(shopdata,parameter = list(supp=0.1,conf=0.8),
                              appearance = list(rhs=c("Ready_made=1")),
                              control = list(verbose=F))
inspect(head(rules_rhs_ready_made[!is.redundant(rules_rhs_ready_made)],by="lift"))
rules_rhs_frozen_foods<-apriori(shopdata,parameter = list(supp=0.1,conf=0.8),
                              appearance = list(rhs=c("Frozen_foods=1")),
                              control = list(verbose=F))
inspect(head(rules_rhs_frozen_foods[!is.redundant(rules_rhs_frozen_foods)],by="lift"))
rules_rhs_Alcohol<-apriori(shopdata,parameter = list(supp=0.1,conf=0.8),
                              appearance = list(rhs=c("Alcohol=1")),
                              control = list(verbose=F))
inspect(head(rules_rhs_Alcohol[!is.redundant(rules_rhs_Alcohol)],by="lift"))
rules_rhs_Fresh_Vegetables<-apriori(shopdata,parameter = list(supp=0.1,conf=0.8),
                              appearance = list(rhs=c("Fresh_Vegetables=1")),
                              control = list(verbose=F))
inspect(head(rules_rhs_Fresh_Vegetables[!is.redundant(rules_rhs_Fresh_Vegetables)],by="lift"))
rules_rhs_Milk<-apriori(shopdata,parameter = list(supp=0.1,conf=0.8),
                              appearance = list(rhs=c("Milk=1")),
                              control = list(verbose=F))
inspect(head(rules_rhs_Milk[!is.redundant(rules_rhs_Milk)],by="lift"))
rules_rhs_Bakery_goods<-apriori(shopdata,parameter = list(supp=0.1,conf=0.8),
                              appearance = list(rhs=c("Bakery_goods=1")),
                              control = list(verbose=F))
inspect(head(rules_rhs_Bakery_goods[!is.redundant(rules_rhs_Bakery_goods)],by="lift"))
rules_rhs_Fresh_meat<-apriori(shopdata,parameter = list(supp=0.1,conf=0.8),
                              appearance = list(rhs=c("Fresh_meat=1")),
                              control = list(verbose=F))
inspect(head(rules_rhs_Fresh_meat[!is.redundant(rules_rhs_Fresh_meat)],by="lift"))
rules_rhs_Toiletries<-apriori(shopdata,parameter = list(supp=0.1,conf=0.8),
                              appearance = list(rhs=c("Toiletries=1")),
                              control = list(verbose=F))
inspect(head(rules_rhs_Toiletries[!is.redundant(rules_rhs_Toiletries)],by="lift"))
rules_rhs_Snacks<-apriori(shopdata,parameter = list(supp=0.1,conf=0.8),
                              appearance = list(rhs=c("Snacks=1")),
                              control = list(verbose=F))
inspect(head(rules_rhs_Snacks[!is.redundant(rules_rhs_Snacks)],by="lift"))
rules_rhs_Tinned_goods<-apriori(shopdata,parameter = list(supp=0.1,conf=0.8),
                              appearance = list(rhs=c("Tinned_goods=1")),
                              control = list(verbose=F))
inspect(head(rules_rhs_Tinned_goods[!is.redundant(rules_rhs_Tinned_goods)],by="lift"))
```
````

When I pressed knit to HTML, it said, "Error: Parser can't have multibyte characters in line 24, stop execution," and didn't show anything else.

Who can tell me what's going on.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a `knitr` error, so it's probably coming from one of the lines of code you're running within it.  You can figure out which one by running them one at a time in the console.  Once you do that, if the error isn't clear, please put together a reproducible example (including data!) and edit it into your question.

Comment: Can you paste line 24 into your question please?